# Is it possible to enrich the default mps text editor?

Tags: mps

I have a xml file(abc.xml) which contains Hyper Links and i open that xml file inside MPS, currently MPS editor for xml/html/txt doesn't handle displaying hyper link, so my question is, is it possible to enrich the mps text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes. But its not MPS specific. It's the text editor from the idea platform that you see there. You can use the normal extension mechanisms of the intelli J platform there.